# Can I create a view in MVC4 (Razor) without having model/ controller like in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view, models, controllers

I have done a few examples in MVC wherein I was declaring my DB in models, then I create my controller and then link a view to each of the methods in Controller.

I have been reading all the net that MVC is loosely coupled. Can you please give me solution on how to generate a View alone for a project without having any models declared.

Comment: Right click the Views folder then add new HTML page?

Comment: @WannaCSharp: Amusing, but that won't be a Razor *view* as requested (no access to inline code etc) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't use a model in your view:

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

View (Index.cshtml)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h1>Hello World!</h1>
The date of today is: @DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't Include a model in your View
controller:

```
public ActionResult ViewName()
{
return View();

}
```

View:

your HTML code